# ¿Cómo deshabilitar algunas opciones de un mat select dependiendo de su valor por default en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

Tengo la siguiente  tabla editable en donde el campo **ESTADO** despliega una lista de los estatus disponibles con un mat select, lo que quiero hacer es deshabilitar algunas opciones dependiendo del valor que ya tiene seteado por default

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo, si el valor que ya trae seteado es igual a INP (INPROGRESS) solo pueda seleccionar el estado FNZ (FINISHED), y que los demás estatus se muestren deshabilitados

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollme">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="select-css" [ngClass]="{'text-red': element.cveEstado=='ERR',
        'text-green': element.cveEstado=='INP', 'text-orange': element.cveEstado=='PEN'}">
            <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar">

              <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [disabled]="deshabilitarOpcion(element.cveEstado).includes(estatus.descripcion)">
                {{ estatus.descripcion }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.horaInicio" (keyup)="changeValueHora($event.target, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar" type="time" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
              (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)" [disabled]="!element.editar" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>GUARDAR</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
          <button mat-button (click)="guardar(element)">Guardar</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { Control } from './Control';
    import { ControlService } from './control.service';
    import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
    import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
    import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
    import { UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
    import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'prueba-angular-material';
      displayedColumns: string[] = [
        'idControl',
        'cveEstado',
        'comentario',
        'horaInicio',
        'fechaRegistro',
        'botonSave',
      ];
      estadoModel: Estado[] = [];
      control: Control[] = [];
      controlModel: Control = new Control();
      estadoSeleccionado: any;
      idSeleccionado: string = '';
      comentIngresado: string = '';
      horaIngresada: string ='';
      fechaIngresada: any;
      dataModel: any[] = [];
      horaInvalida = true;
      
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
    
      constructor(
        private controlService: ControlService,
        private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
      ) {
        this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.obtenerLista();
        this.obtenerListaEstados();
        
      }
    
      //obtiene la lista del servicio
      dataSource: any;
      private obtenerLista() {
        this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
          this.control = response.data;
          console.log("PRUEBA " ,response.data);
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
      }
    
      //obtiene la lista de estados para el select
      private obtenerListaEstados() {
        this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe((response) => {
          console.log("PRUEBA  estados" ,response.data);
          this.estadoModel = response.data;
        });
      }
    
      //obtiene la cve del estado que se selecciona y su id
      cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
        this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
        this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;
    
        console.log(' ID SELECC ' + this.idSeleccionado);
        console.log(' ESTADO SELECC ' + this.estadoSeleccionado);
      }
    
      //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input coment  y el id
      changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
        this.comentIngresado = e.value;
        console.log(' INPUT COMENT  ' + this.comentIngresado);
      }
    
     //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input hora, y el id
     changeValueHora(e: any, row: any) {
      this.horaIngresada = e.value;
      console.log(' INPUT HORA   ' +this.horaIngresada);
      this.validarHora();
    }
    
    validarHora() {
      console.log(' ENTRA A VALIDAR HORA');
      const regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$");
      this.horaInvalida = !regex.test(this.horaIngresada);
      console.log('HORA '  + this.horaInvalida);
    }
    
    
      //OBTIENE EL VALOR DE LA FECHA SELECCIONADA
      onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
        this.fechaIngresada = valor;
        console.log('FECHA SELECC  ' + this.fechaIngresada);
      }
    
      //funcion para darle formato a la fecha internamente
      formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
        if (date) {
          const format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
          const locale = 'en-US';
          return formatDate(date, format, locale);
        }
        return '';
      }

 deshabilitarOpcion(cveEstado: string): string[] {
     console.log("PRUEBA CVE     ",cveEstado);
    switch (cveEstado) {
      case 'INP':
        console.log("entra aqui    ");
        return ['ERR','PEN'];
      case 'ERR':
        return ['PEN','FNZ'];
      default:
        return [];
    }
  }
    
      guardar(element: any) {
        if (element.editar) {
          console.log(`Desactivado para ${element.idControl}`);
          element.editar = false;
    
          if (this.comentIngresado == '') {
            alert('No se han modificado campos');
          } else {
            console.log(' ENTRA ELSE  ');
            this.controlModel.cveEstado = this.estadoSeleccionado;
            this.controlModel.comentario = this.comentIngresado;
            this.controlModel.idControl = this.idSeleccionado;
            this.controlModel.fechaRegistro = this.formatDateToString(
              this.fechaIngresada
            );
    
            console.log('prueba fecha final  ' + this.controlModel.fechaRegistro);
            this.controlService
              .updateCampo(this.controlModel)
              .subscribe((data) => {
                this.controlModel = data;
                this.comentIngresado = '';
                this.estadoSeleccionado = '';
                this.fechaIngresada = '';
    
                alert('Agregado correctamente');
              });
          }
        } else {
          console.log(`Activado para ${element.idControl}`);
          element.editar = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

como se podría agregar esa validacion para deshabilitar los estatus dependiendo el valor que ya trae

UPDATE
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar ternarios, `if-else` anidados, aunque en este caso prefiero un switch case para hacerlo más legible y fácil de entender. Como tienes varias opciones podemos usar un arreglo para regresar los datos.

**Componente**

```
  deshabilitarOpcion(estado: string): string[] {
    switch (estado) {
      case 'Iniciado':
        return ['Finalizado'];
      case 'En Proceso':
        return ['Iniciado'];
      case 'Finalizado':
        return ['Iniciado', 'En Proceso', 'Error'];
      case 'Error':
        return ['En Proceso', 'Finalizado'];
      default:
        return [];
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-select [value]="row.estado">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let estado of estados" [value]="estado"
    [disabled]="deshabilitarOpcion(row.estado).includes(estado)">
    {{ estado }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: gracias, cómo va la lógica? si el valor por default es "Iniciado"  , regresa Finalizado, o sea que finalizado va a  estar deshabilitado? o solo Finalizado va a estar habilitado y los demas estatus no?

Comment: es que lo agregue pero no me hace nada, todos me siguen apareciendo habilitados

Comment: Si estas usando la propiedad `[disabled]`, lo que regrese son los valores que se van a desactivar.

Comment: Si, agregué  la propiedad disabled asi como en el ejemplo, pero no deshabilita las opciones, me sigue dejando seleccionarlas

Comment: Prueba estableciendo un valor por defecto para que se deshabilite la opción, recuerdo que tenías problemas con `[value]` así que es probable que sea lo mismo.

Comment: en donde se establece el valor por default? en el option?  , actualice a como lo tengo ahorita agregando lo del ejemplo

Comment: Es que lo tienes mal, el valor que va primero es el valor original `element.cveEstado` y el otro parece que sería `estatus.descripción`, en tu código `cveEstado` no es nada por si solo.

Comment: lo que va en includes? ya lo cambie asi   [disabled]="deshabilitarOpcion(element.cveEstado).includes(estatus.descripcion)"  pero no hace nada

Comment: Ya cheque el error, lo que tienes es que los valores que tienes en el `switch` son diferentes de lo que muestras. Tienes INP pero muestras In Progress. Tienen que usar los valores que muestras porque esta comparando los strings del `mat-option`.

Comment: actualice a como lo tengo ahorita, si cambio a la descripcion "INPROGRESS" , no entra al console.log que puse en el primer case

Comment: Ya me funcionó,  muchas gracias.  Lo cambíe asi y ya lo toma --- >   case 'INP':
        return ['FINISHED','PENDING'];